# Migrate mongodb to mysql?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

as google isn't really helpful here:

what's the best way of migrating a mongodb database to a mysql database? any best practise examples?

thanks!

Comment: I think would have been better served being migrated to server fault, it's a valid question, just not a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you have completed scarpacci's exercise and have an idea of the mappings, I would then look at [mongoexport](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongoexport) - you should be careful about type fidelity though and then you will have to import the CSV/TSV into MySQL in a sane manner also.

The other option, especially if you run into typing issues, is to simply pull all of your data out programmatically using your language and driver of choice and insert it directly into MySQL, again using your favorite driver - this gives the most control, but is also the most work.

Comment: +1 didn't know about mongoexport cool tip Adam

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit of a non-starter, because people usually implement things in Mongo or other NoSQL databases in order to have a schemaless design.  That is diametrically opposed to the concept of a relational database.

Without looking at the sort of data structures you have in Mongo, this would be impossible to answer.

Answer (score 3):

@Tronic I would start by utilizing the mappings MongoDB provides on their site:

[Mapping Guide](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart)

I would then try and take your documents in each of your collections and try to break those out into the proper DB Entities (Tables).  The entities / attributes could be difficult to design based on the schemaless design of Mongo (As @Mike Brant indicates)

Hope this helps.

--S